# LabVIEW Keithley 6485 driver

Tags: driver, labview

I am using the Keithley 6485 driver on LabVIEW. I am having a hard time keeping zero check and zero correct on.
Here is the code I am using.
I turn zero check on but it turns off as soon as measurements are triggered.
I am having a similar problem with zero correct.
Ideally, I want to turn on zero check, turn on zero correct, and then turn off zero check before measuring the current.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Keithley 6485 manual (section 3-4?), it describes how one combines zero check with zero correct manually, which I bet is the same procedure you should follow in your code (quote below with some edits):

1. Enable zero check.
2. Select the range that will be used for the measurement.
3. Perform ZCOR (or REL on 6487)
4. Disable zero check.
5. Take the readings. The readings will have the zero correct factor applied (it sounds like a "zero offset").

The above is done before/after inputting a signal.

The inside baseball takeaway is that the zero check feature causes the input amplifier to be shunted to ground; it is an internal hardware feature to get a good zero reading which you perform with the zero correct feature. Zero check is meant to be off when you are actively taking a measurement.

The takeaway for your code is to add/modify *before* your while loop: enable zero check, select measurement range, do zero correct, disable zero check. Inside while, measure inside while loop to monitor measurement. Zero check is meant to be off; zero correct is not repeated while measurement is running.